# Multiple filters in Lucene.net

Tags: search, filter, lucene.net

How to combine multiple filters within one search?

For example I have record with analyzable field **title** and not analyzable fields **id1**, **id2**, **id3**, **release_date**. I want to find all records using specific filters for id1, id2, id3 and release_date; So, I have:

```
RangeFilter refReleaseDateFilter = new RangeFilter("release_date",
            refFromDateTimeTerm.Text(), refToDateTimeTerm.Text(), true, true);

RangeFilter refId1Filter = new RangeFilter("id1",
            refFromId1Term.Text(), refToId1Term.Text(), true, true);

RangeFilter refId2Filter = new RangeFilter("id2",
            refFromId2Term.Text(), refToId2Term.Text(), true, true);

RangeFilter refId3Filter = new RangeFilter("id3",
            refFromId3Term.Text(), refToId3Term.Text(), true, true);
```

But the method **Search** of class **IndexSearcher** does not provide array of filters.

Please help me:) Thank you!:)

Answer (score 3):

You may use something like a ChainedFilter

see.: http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_0/api/contrib-misc/org/apache/lucene/misc/ChainedFilter.html

there is also a ChainedFilter in the .net distribution of lucene.

http://www.koders.com/csharp/fidB8682543372DDC9772496D453F39957A94E58466.aspx?s=system#L3

Another option would be to implement it as a port of the java application it is not that much code.

Comment: fyr thank you, but as I understood ChainedFilter was not implemented in .Net port of Lucene.

Comment: I edited this with a reference to this. There are also several mailinglist posts regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Using a single `BooleanQuery` worked for me with Lucene.NET 3.0.3:

```
var filters = new BooleanQuery();
filters.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("ancestor_path", path)), Occur.MUST);
filters.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("resource_type", "page")), Occur.MUST);
var filter = new QueryWrapperFilter(filters);
```